# How to substitute a given data structure by Json string?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have the following code in Python. It takes a datimetime `dt` and checks if it belongs to `Type1` or `Type2`. If none of these types is triggered, then `None` is returned:

```
self.daytypes = {
    'Type1': (
        date(2015, 3, 12),
        date(2015, 4, 8)
    ),
    'Type2': (
        date(2015, 1, 4),
        date(2015, 3, 9),
        date(2015, 5, 25)
    )
}


def getDayType(self,dt):
    holidays = []
    for d in self.daytypes:
        holidays.extend(self.daytypes[d])

    wd = dt.isoweekday()
    daytype = None 
    for t, ranges in self.daytypes.items():
        for day in ranges:
            if (day == dt.date()):
                daytype = t
                break
        if daytype is not None:
            break
    return daytype
```

Now I want to substitute the data structure `self.daytypes` by a Json string `myJson`:

```
{"Type1":["2015-03-12","2015-04-08"],"Type2":["2015-01-04","2015-03-09","2015-05-25"]}
```

Is there any easy way to make it with minimal updates of the code?

Comment: do you want to set self.daytypes from your json?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed: yes, I am searching for an optimal solution. In my opinion the most optimal way is to set `self.daytypes` from json without changing the rest of code (i.e. the function `getDayType`). However, if you have another proposal, you are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the data structure from the JSON string using a dictionary comprehension, like this:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

json_string = '''{"Type1":["2015-03-12","2015-04-08"],"Type2":["2015-01-04","2015-03-09","2015-05-25"]}'''

daytypes = {k: [datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for x in v] for k,v in json.loads(json_string).items()}

>>> daytypes
{'Type1': [datetime.date(2015, 3, 12), datetime.date(2015, 4, 8)], 'Type2': [datetime.date(2015, 1, 4), datetime.date(2015, 3, 9), datetime.date(2015, 5, 25)]}
```

If you must have tuples in your dictionary then you can convert the list into a tuple in the dict comprehension:

```
daytypes = {k: tuple(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for x in v) for k,v in json.loads(json_string).items()}
>>> daytypes
{u'Type1': (datetime.date(2015, 3, 12), datetime.date(2015, 4, 8)), u'Type2': (datetime.date(2015, 1, 4), datetime.date(2015, 3, 9), datetime.date(2015, 5, 25))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement function for serializing:

```
def toJSON(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, 
        sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Could you please post an exact output of this function for the given input Json string?

Comment: It looks like just as you want.

Comment: If I do this `daytypes = toJSON({"Type1":["2015-03-12","2015-04-08"],"Type2":["2015-01-04","2015-03-09","2015-05-25"]})`, and then run my code without changing anything, I get this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`